# For loop in R with increments

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop which will increment its value by 2. The equivalent code is c is

```
for (i=0; i<=78; i=i+2)
```

How do I achieve the same in R?

Comment: please post a more complete example... in R it's probable that you don't actually want a for loop.

Answer (score 66):

See `?seq` for more info:

```
for(i in seq(from=1, to=78, by=2)){
#  stuff, such as
  print(i)
}
```

or

```
for(i in seq(1, 78, 2))
```

p.s. Pardon my C ignorance. There, I just outed myself.

However, this is a way to do what you want in R (please see updated code)

**EDIT**

After learning a bit of how C works, it looks like the example posted in the question iterates over the following sequence: `0 2 4 6 8 ... 74 76 78`.

To replicate that exactly in R, start at `0` instead of at `1`, as above.

```
seq(from=0, to=78, by=2)
 [1]  0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 42 44
[24] 46 48 50 52 54 56 58 60 62 64 66 68 70 72 74 76 78
```

Comment: @Probabilityman It is probably worth adding, that often using a `for loop` is unnecessary in R.  If you supply a more complete example of your specific problem (or ask another question), it is quite possible that the `for loop` can be omitted completely. For example, `print(seq(1,72,2))` does the same thing as the code supplied by BenBarnes.

Comment: ... and @Justin's example is much faster. Search the internets for "r for loops" for some more info.

Comment: @Justin, print(seq(1,72,2)) does produce different output.  The loop prints each element as a 1-tuple (on its own line).  Not that this is to be preferred.  If the loop can be replaced by a vector operation (or apply), it probably should be.

Comment: @Justin, the code within the loop can sometimes be convoluted and the loop index is just a tiny part, in which case, vectorization is out.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik good point.  I just wanted to point out that often, given a more complete example, the solutions offered will be more "R" like and often can loose the loop entirely.  However, its very true that sometimes there is no avoiding them!

Answer (score 1):

you can do so in following way, you can put any length upto which you want iteration in place of length(v1), and the increment value at position of 2 to your desired value

```
for(i in seq(1,length(v1),2))
```