# decimal increments in loop for R

Tags: r, loops, decimal

I would like to find the value of "p" below (which is between 0 and 1), knowing the following equations:

- `RI_26 = min(IR,na.rm=FALSE)`
- `RI_min = 100-(sse*SUM/((1+p)*Dotation2017*100))^(1/p)`

where **RI_26** is the minimum of resources index of my 26 area. It is a constant in my case. In RI_min, **sse and Dotations2017** are 2 constants and **p** is a unknown. I know that **RI_26 should be equal to RI_min**.

It would be easy to solve it, but **SUM** (which is present in RI_min) is as well unknown as it is a **function of p** as following:

```
`sum.function = function(p){
  SUM <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
  for(i in 1:length(Canton))
    if(IR[i] < 100) {
      SUM[i] <- (100-IR[i])^(1+p)*Pop[i]
      SUM[27] <- SUM[27]+SUM[i]
    }
  SUM <- round(SUM,0)
  return(SUM[27])
}

SUM = sum.function(p)
```

SUM returns a number (or vector 1X1). To deal with it, I would like to find the value of p that satisfied:

- RI_26/RI_min = 1

To do so, I would like to do a loop, beginning with p = 0 and then increasing the value of p by 0.01 until it reaches 1. The loop should return the value of p_star when the constraint is True (RI_26/RI_min = 1.00).

I don't have any idea how to do this but it could look like the following code:

```
p.function = function(){

  for(...)
    if(RI_26/RI_min = 1.000000) {
      p_star <- p

    }

  return(p_star)
}
```

So the function will return the value of p_star when RI_26/RI_min = 1.000000. What am I suppose to write in my function: p.function to increment "p" and have the result that I want? Any idea?

Comment: ```for i in seq(0, 1, 0.1) {}``` should do the trick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For loop in R with increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287364/for-loop-in-r-with-increments)

Comment: `for (i in (0:10)/10)  { print(i) }`

Comment: Read the [Vector arithmetic](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Vector-arithmetic) section in the documentation. You don't really need a loop. Also, in the future, make sure you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

```
for (i in seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)) {
    "Your code here"
}
```