# How does inverted comma work inside sprintf?

Tags: r, error-handling, sprint

I want an output such as

```
N(X(1), newx="gen")
```

I tried to use the following code

```
try1 <- sprintf("N(X(,%d),newx="gen" )",seq.int(1))
```

But the above R code gives error. Now how could I do this with sprintf? Any suggestion is extremely appreciated. nb i am quite new to r.

Comment: Can you include the complete error message from R ?

Comment: I think (I know nothing about R) you can do: `for(i in seq.int(4) sprintf("N(X(,%d),newx="gen" )",i))`. (see also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287457/724039 )

Comment: @Luuk this is the error message, Error: unexpected symbol in "sprintf("N(X(,%d),newx="gen"

Comment: @Luuk thanks.. but your code is showing,Error: unexpected symbol in "for(i in seq.int(4) sprintf"

Comment: You should escape the quotation marks, see the given answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [escape the quotation marks](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html):

```
result <- sprintf("N(X(%d), newx=\"gen\")", seq.int(4))
cat(result, sep = "\n")
```

---

Regarding OP's edit:

```
result <- paste(sprintf("N(X(%d), newx=\"gen\")", seq.int(4)), collapse="+")
cat(result)
```

Comment: `cat(s, sep = "\n")`

Comment: And `sprintf('N(X(,%d),newx="gen" )',seq.int(4))` might be a bit easier on the eyes.

Comment: @user1296755 What do you intend to do with the character string? The quotation marks must be escaped, there is no way around that. However, that is not an issue because the backslashes should disappear when you export the string. Or you can use `cat` if you are concerned about printing to the R console.

Comment: @user1296755 Then you should change your whole approach. You should not have R code as a character string in R. Anyway, the parser will understand `\"` as `"`.